# How to make user inputs only accept string and not any integers. Without the use of any python modules

Tags: python-3.x

**Numbers** cannot be accepted into the input but only letters.

```
ans = str(input('Select an option?'))

if ans=="A":
    if len(array) < 10:
        A = list(input('\nInput string: \n'))
        while True:
            try:
                A = list(input('\nInput string: \n'))
                if A not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0):
                    raise ValueError()
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Numbers are not accepted')
        if len(A) == 1 and str(A):
            array += A
        if len(A) >= 2:
            print('Only single digit inputs allowed')
        if len(array) == 10:
            print( "Invalid input\n")   

elif ans=="P":
    print(' '.join(array))
```

The input currently doesn't accept any input and is stuck in a constant loop of not accepting it, I only want letters to be accepted for the input and that it only asks the user once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Numbers cannot be accepted into the input but only letters.

I think this is a job for `isinstance()`, i.e.:

```
if isinstance(A, str):
    # A is a string
```

Comment: How can this be implemented into the code and how does it work?

Comment: It returns `true` or `false`, in this case, it will return `true` because `A` is a string, you change to other types, like `int`, `list` etc.